# Oracle PL/SQL UTL_FILE.PUT buffering

Tags: oracle, plsql, put, fflush, utl-file

I'm writing a large file > 7MB from an Oracle stored procedure and the requirements are to have no line termination characters (no carriage return/line feed) at the end of each record.

I've written a stored procedure using UTL_FILE.PUT and I'm following each call to UTL_FILE.PUT with a UTL_FILE.FFLUSH.  This procedure errors with a write error once I get to the point where I've written more than the buffer size (set to max 32767) although I'm making the FFLUSH calls.  The procedure works fine if I replace the PUT calls with PUT_LINE calls.

Is it not possible to write more than the buffer size without a newline character?  If so, is there a work around?

Answer (score 4):

Dustin,

The Oracle documentation here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003404

States that:
**FFLUSH physically writes pending data to the file identified by the file handle. Normally, data being written to a file is buffered. The FFLUSH procedure forces the buffered data to be written to the file. The data must be terminated with a newline character.**

The last sentence being the most pertinent.

Could you not write the data using UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE before then searching the resulting file for the line terminators and removing them?

Just a thought....

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how FFLUSH works, I hadn't seen the last sentence in my searches.

Comment: Hi @Ollie , I am still confused about how FFLUSH works, for(1-->32767 +n), every time I put, and I fflush. Why should a new line still needed ? Would you help to explain?

Answer (score 4):

*deleted quote from docs, see Ollie's answer*

Another possible way to do this is a Java stored procedure, where you can use the more full-featured Java API for creating and writing to files.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the java stored procedure.  Although I believe the Java code itself would be straightforward, we don't do any java coding in our shop, so it would be a maintenance issue for someone to have to pick up.

Comment: Would you please help to explain how we can resolve this problem with BFILE Object?

Comment: @Jaskey, actually I think I was incorrect about that.  I believe that BFILEs are read-only so couldn't be used to write data out to an OS file.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is less than desirable, you could always `PUT` until you have detected that you are nearing the buffer size. When this occurs, you can `FCLOSE` the file handle (flushing the buffer) and re-open that same file with `FOPEN` using `'a'` (append) as the mode. Again, this technique should generally be avoided, especially if other processes are also trying to access the file (for example: closing a file usually revokes any locks the process had placed upon it, freeing up any other processes that were trying to acquire a lock).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great responses, they have been very helpful.  The java stored procedure looked like the way to go, but since we don't have a lot of java expertise in-house, it would be frowned upon by management.  But, I was able to find a way to do this from the stored procedure.  I had to open the file in write byte mode 'WB'.  Then, for each record I'm writing to the file, I convert it to the RAW datatype with UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW.  Then use UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW to write to the file followed by any necessary FFLUSH calls to flush the buffers.  The receiving system has been able to read the files; so far so good.