# What are common Causes for WRITE_ERROR,Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, file-io, plsql, runtime-error, utl-file

Recently, I encountered many `UTL.FILE.WRITE_ERROR` , but the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm) does  not explain all the causes.

For example: [Oracle PL/SQL UTL_FILE.PUT buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206312/oracle-pl-sql-utl-file-put-buffering) describes one situation that causes this issue that when we called `put`(even we `fflush` after every single char) to write to a file without new line terminator.

Hope to summarize the common causes for this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation explains that `UTL_FILE.WRITE_ERROR` is an exception that gets thrown on a `Operating system error occurred during the write operation.` So the exception has nothing to do with the UTL_FILE package itself but is thrown as a consequence of an OS related error that has occured.
Based on the [other exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#i996873) that are thrown on more specific errors I would say that the two most common causes for a WRITE_ERROR exception are:

- Out of space
- File deletion during write operation

Comment: Something is more tricky actually, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206312/oracle-pl-sql-utl-file-put-buffering